# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function while using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I am trying to implement routing in my Weather App project , What I am trying to achieve is that when I click on cityname , it should be displayed in another app. But somehow I get below error `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function` 
Below is my files :

My App.js

```
   const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Header />
            <WeatherData />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/cities">
            <Header />
            <Cities />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/cities/:val" component={DataNaman}/>
        </Switch>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};
```

My Next Component file when:

```
import React, { useParams } from "react";

const DataNaman = () => {
  debugger;
  let { val } = useParams();

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Naman</h1>
    </>
  );
};

export default DataNaman;
```

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no `useParams` in the react library?

i expect you use `react-router`? then you should import the `useParams` from there.

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
```

Comment: Thanks buddy , I never gave it a look , I thought that it will automatically import it correctly